# Update fields on join based upon count in 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I need to update two fields (Trans.PtPlanId and Trans.PtLot) based upon a join and a count in the joined table. The join works, but not the update.

This join returns the correct rows:

```
SELECT
    Plan.Prp_PartNum AS PartNum,
    Count(Plan.Prp_PartNum) AS PartNum_Count,
    Plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
    Plan.Prp_Lot,
    Trans.PtPlanId,
    Trans.PtLot
FROM
    prod_plan AS Plan
LEFT JOIN product_trans AS Trans ON Trans.PtPartNum = Plan.Prp_PartNum
WHERE
    IFNULL(plan.Prp_Closed,0) = 0 AND
    Trans.PtRole = 'XBO' AND
    Trans.PtPosted IS NULL
GROUP BY
    Plan.Prp_PartNum,
    Plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
    Plan.Prp_Lot
HAVING
    PartNum_Count = 1
ORDER BY
    PartNum ASC
```

The following update yields an [Err] 1064:

```
UPDATE product_trans AS Trans
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Plan.Prp_PartNum AS PartNum,
        Count(Plan.Prp_PartNum) AS PartNum_Count,
        Plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
        Plan.Prp_Lot
    FROM
        prod_plan
    WHERE
        IFNULL(plan.Prp_Closed, 0) = 0
    GROUP BY
        Plan.Prp_PartNum,
        Plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
        Plan.Prp_Lot
    HAVING
        Plan.PartNum_Count = 1
    ORDER BY
        Plan.Prp_PartNum ASC
) AS Plan 

ON Trans.PtPartNum AS Trans = Plan.Prp_PartNum

SET Trans.PtPlanId = Plan.Prp_ProdPlanId,
 Trans.PtLot = Plan.Prp_Lot

WHERE
Trans.PtRole = 'XBO' AND
Trans.PtPosted IS NULL
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have to remove `AS Trans` from the `ON` clause.

Comment: You should add it as an answer @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: When I remove it I get: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Plan.Prp_PartNum' in 'field list'

Comment: You have to use `Plan.PartNum`  because the alias in the derived table obscures the field `Plan.Prp_PartNum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated per comments posted:

```
UPDATE product_trans AS Trans
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        prod_plan.Prp_PartNum AS PartNum,
        Count(prod_plan.Prp_PartNum) AS PartNum_Count,
        prod_plan.Prp_ProdPlanId AS Plan_Id,
        prod_plan.Prp_Lot AS Lot
    FROM
        prod_plan
    WHERE
        IFNULL(prod_plan.Prp_Closed, 0) = 0
    GROUP BY
        PartNum,
        Plan_Id,
        Lot
    HAVING
        PartNum_Count = 1
    ORDER BY
        Prp_PartNum ASC
) AS Plan 

ON Trans.PtPartNum = Plan.PartNum

SET Trans.PtPlanId = Plan.Plan_Id,
 Trans.PtLot = Plan.Lot

WHERE
Trans.PtRole = 'XBO' AND
Trans.PtPosted IS NULL
```